# How to calculate % change based on varying years and column_name

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe like the one below

```
Index     Toronto_2000   Toronto_2001    Toronto_2002    Toronto_2003    Montreal_2000  Montreal_2001   Montreal_2002   Montreal_2003
ID:1012          100            98              102             105             101             104             108            110
```

How can I calculate the % change for each of the years and separate for each city?

- Like calculate df.pct_change() for 2001, 2002, 2003 given that there are different cities

Comment: Forgive me, but it seems like your dataframe columns are organized poorly. I'd suggest first reorganizing it as: Index, City, Year, Value. This will make everything easier.

Comment: @fabio.avigo I am aware the data is not ideally formatted.  This isn't my creation.    There are a bunch of index values that have to be in place.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest first reshape `DataFrame` by [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)  and then use [`pct_change`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.pct_change.html) with `groupby`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df = df.unstack().reset_index()
df.columns = ['city','year','index','val']
print (df)
       city  year    index  val
0   Toronto  2000  ID:1012  100
1   Toronto  2001  ID:1012   98
2   Toronto  2002  ID:1012  102
3   Toronto  2003  ID:1012  105
4  Montreal  2000  ID:1012  101
5  Montreal  2001  ID:1012  104
6  Montreal  2002  ID:1012  108
7  Montreal  2003  ID:1012  110

df['pct'] = df.groupby('city')['val'].apply(lambda x: x.pct_change()) 
print (df)
       city  year    index  val       pct
0   Toronto  2000  ID:1012  100       NaN
1   Toronto  2001  ID:1012   98 -0.020000
2   Toronto  2002  ID:1012  102  0.040816
3   Toronto  2003  ID:1012  105  0.029412
4  Montreal  2000  ID:1012  101       NaN
5  Montreal  2001  ID:1012  104  0.029703
6  Montreal  2002  ID:1012  108  0.038462
7  Montreal  2003  ID:1012  110  0.018519
```

Comment: question,  on my answer, do you know why the first Montreal value is not NaN?

Comment: @Yuca - unfortunately bug.

Comment: the way around it is to do `apply`?

Comment: @Yuca - I think yes.

Comment: @jezrael what if there are multiple Toronto_2000 data with just different index values.   Would you use a combined groupby statement?  I tried this but it didn't work df.groupby('city,'index')

Comment: @OptimusPrime - Sure, use `df['pct'] = df.groupby(['city', 'index'])['val'].apply(lambda x: x.pct_change()) `

Answer (score 0):

This is the long way around it, maybe a pro gives you a beautiful one liner

```
df2 = df.T.reset_index()
df2['city'] = [x[0] for x in df2['index'].str.split('_')]
df2['year'] = [x[1] for x in df2['index'].str.split('_')]
df2['pct'] = df2.sort_values('year').groupby(['city'])['ID:1012'].pct_change()
```

#### output

```
Index          index  ID:1012      city  year       pct
0       Toronto_2000      100   Toronto  2000       NaN
1       Toronto_2001       98   Toronto  2001 -0.029703
2       Toronto_2002      102   Toronto  2002 -0.019231
3       Toronto_2003      105   Toronto  2003 -0.027778
4      Montreal_2000      101  Montreal  2000  0.010000
5      Montreal_2001      104  Montreal  2001  0.061224
6      Montreal_2002      108  Montreal  2002  0.058824
7      Montreal_2003      110  Montreal  2003  0.047619
```